# Error during cap deploy

Tags: capistrano

I have installed gem **capistrano** and now I am trying to **cap deploy** from a test branch, but it is giving some error and the cap deploy is failing.

Here is the error stacktrace :

`LoadError: no such file to load -- jruby_pageant
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/agent/java_pageant.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/agent.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/agent.rb:20
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/key_manager.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/key_manager.rb:4
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/session.rb:1
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/
authentication/session.rb:4
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh.
rb:1
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh.
rb:11
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/
net/ssh/gateway.rb:2
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capi
strano/configuration/connections.rb:2
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
  require at c:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
   (root) at c:\jruby-1.7.2\bin\cap:23`

Can someone please help on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either install capistrano with jruby -S and if you have ruby and jruby on your system make ruby prior in your PATH

Comment: Hi @Cthulhu, I have added the ruby path in the PATH. Now it is working fine. Thanks.